# C# problem querying dbase file; problem using WHERE clause

Tags: c#, sql, dbase

I'm querying a dbase .dbf file with odbc from within my c# code and am having a problem using a 'where' clause in my query.  I can retrieve and read the records fine if I just 'select * from FILE.DBF', and every example I see on web pages as I search for an answer show just that much syntax.  I've tried multiple ways of constructing the select statement with a 'where' and so far they all fail.  So, I'm wondering whether I just can NOT use a 'where' clause in a query against a dbase file, or whether I simply haven't hit on the correct syntax yet.

I've tried:

```
select * from FILE.DBF where GROUP = 21;
select * from FILE.DBF where GROUP = '21';
select * from FILE.DBF where GROUP = "21";
```

The result of all of these is the error: ERROR [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC dBase Driver] Syntax error in WHERE clause.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try surrounding the word GROUP with brackets ... as in ..

select * from FILE.DBF where [GROUP] = 21;

GROUP is a SQL keyword and it's most likely causing some issues.

Answer (score 1):

GROUP is a keyword used for SQL itself. Try running the same query but with a different 'where' clause, by substituting 'Group' with another field instead (and a different condition too, naturally). If the query works, then 'GROUP' is being mixed up with the SQL syntax for GROUP BY, and thus you might need to use brackets or some other character to enclose the field name.